# Write a message on the 8th row of a textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea with a limited row, and i have a button which as soon i click it, it will add my name.
I want my name to be on the 8th row even if i wrote a text from the 1st row to the 7th one.

Is there a way to do it please ?

This is my code it will only add my name after a message on the textarea :

```
   const messageTextarea = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('message'));
const selecStart = messageTextarea.selectionStart;
const selectEnd = messageTextarea.selectionEnd;
console.log(selectEnd)
let newmes = '' + this.message;
newmes = newmes.substring(0, selecStart)+ newmes.substring(selectEnd, newmes.length)+this.user.firstname;
this.updateView(newmes);
```

Comment: How do you know it is the 8th row? Is it actual rows with line breaks or word wrap?

Comment: My textarea is limited to 8th row, so if i write more then this the message will not be shown.

Comment: I would use string manipulation, grab the value of textarea, split on newline character "\n", if your array length is less than or equal to 8 add newline characters until at the 8th row and add your name, else replace the value or append the value of array for line 8 with your name, then Join the array values back together with newline characters and replace textarea value.

Comment: Not sure how it is limited to number of rows....  You mean `<textare rows="8"`?

Comment: @RyanWilson could you show me how ?

Comment: I know i have to be to the 120 char position is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I was saying:

```
       let someText = "Hi \n How \n are \n you?"; //This would be replaced with your textarea value
       let stringSplit = someText.split('\n');


       if (stringSplit.length < 8)
       {
           //Add enough items to be 8 rows
           for(let x = stringSplit.length; x < 8; x++)
           {
               stringSplit.push("");
           }
       }

       //replace the 8th row value with your name
       stringSplit[7] = "YourName";

       //Join the array back into a string separated by newline between each element value
       someText = stringSplit.join('\n');
       //Set your textarea value = someText
```

Comment: Is It javascript ?

Comment: Sorry, it's C# code I wrote, but you could basically do the same with javascript.

Comment: @Taieb Edited answer to convert it to javascript code.

Comment: Is there a way to put my name directly on the 121 position of the textarea ?

Comment: When you say the 121 position, do you mean the string index of 121?

Comment: yes yes yes, with this way i'm sure i will have my name on the perfect position.

Comment: Your string may not be that long, depends on the other values in the textarea, and how long each string value is on each row.

Comment: The row is limmited to 21 char